# Google Assistant plugin(App actions test tool) gives error - Preview Creation Error

Tags: android-studio, google-assistant, app-actions

On Android studio dolphin,
Google assistant plugin(App actions test tool) 2.4.0 and 2.5.0 gives following error in a project already having my_shortcuts.xml

```
*Preview Creation Error Status Code: 500 Message: Internal error encountered. Create shortcuts.xml*

I am on M1 Chip mac and Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 and trying this in Pixel API 30 emulator
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-login and re-open the Android Studio.